# How to interpret 'null' param in documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I am going through the bcrypt-nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs documentation and it says in the basic usage:

```
bcrypt.hash("bacon", null, null, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});
```

Should I leave null in my code or not?

Comment: That package is deprecated, I recommend you to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt, the most up-to-date one

Comment: If you are referring an external lib function , then better to put a reference to the original documentation of the external lib function . In this case you may leave it a null and put a foot note which refers to the external documentation.

Comment: It's not the documentation per se, it's just an example of how the function can be used. The actual docs (under "API" down the page) say `hash(data, salt, progress, cb)`, so the first null stands for  "salt" (=no salt) and the second one is "progress" (=no progress). Of course, you can provide other values depending on what you need. Good luck!